# How do I merge tab-delimited files?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have 3 tab-delimited files as shown below:

File 1:

```
1   Hhe.7
2   Hpyl.1
10  Hac.2
```

File 2:

```
3   Hac.2
15  Hpyl.1
33  Hhe.7
```

File 3:

```
70  Hpyl.1
23  Hhe.7
9   Hac.2
```

How do I merge these files (using the command line) in one file to obtain the following output:

```
1  33  23  Hhe.7
2  15  70  Hpyl.1
10  3  9  Hac.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a small python script, you can combine an *unlimited* number of files:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

#read the files, split the lines for reordering
lines = sum([[l.strip().split() for l in open(f).readlines()]\
             for f in sys.argv[1:]], [])
# get the unique last sections
values = set(map(lambda x:x[1], lines))
# combine them with the combined first sections
newlist = [[y[0] for y in lines if y[1]==x]+[x] for x in values]
for l in newlist:
    print(("\t").join(l))
```

Copy it into an empty file, save it as `merge.py`, run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/merge.py file1, file2, file3 (file4, file5 etc.)
```

Output on your example files:

```
10  3   9   Hac.2
1   33  23  Hhe.7
2   15  70  Hpyl.1
```

#### Adding more files

As mentioned, the number of files is in principle unlimited, if I add a 4th file:

```
40   Hhe.7
50   Hpyl.1
60   Hac.2
```

and run the command:

```
python3 /path/to/merge.py file1, file2, file3, file4
```

the output will be:

```
40  23  33  1   Hhe.7
50  70  15  2   Hpyl.1
60  9   3   10  Hac.2
```

Comment: @kos you can do unlimited files with a oneliner: `awk '{a[$NF]=$1"\t"a[$NF];} END{for(i in a){print a[i],i}}' file1 file2 file3 fileN `

Answer (score 4):

The classic UNIX tool for this is `join`:

```
NAME
       join - join lines of two files on a common field

SYNOPSIS
       join [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2

DESCRIPTION
       For  each  pair of input lines with identical join fields, write a line
       to standard output.  The default join field is the first, delimited  by
       blanks.
```

However, `join` i) needs its input to be sorted in order to work and ii) can only deal with 2 files. So, you could do something ugly and inelegant like:

1. Sort each file on the second field and save as a new file

   ```
   sort -k2 file1 > sorted1
   sort -k2 file2 > sorted2
   sort -k2 file3 > sorted3
   ```
2. Join files 1 and 2 into a new file and then join the third

   ```
   $ join -j2 --nocheck-order sorted1 sorted2 > newfile
   $ join -o 1.2,1.3,2.1,1.1  -1 1 -2 2 --nocheck-order newfile sorted3 
   10 3 9 Hac.2
   1 33 23 Hhe.7
   2 15 70 Hpyl.1
   ```

   The options used are:

   ```
      -1 FIELD
             join on this FIELD of file 1

      -2 FIELD
             join on this FIELD of file 2
      -j FIELD
             equivalent to '-1 FIELD -2 FIELD'

      --nocheck-order
             do not check that the input is correctly sorted

      -o FORMAT
             obey FORMAT while constructing output line
      FORMAT is one or more  comma  or  blank  separated
      specifications, each being 'FILENUM.FIELD' or '0'.
   ```

   So, that command will join on the 1st field of the first file and the 2nd field of the second file, and will print the 2nd field of the first file (`1.2`), then the third field of the first file (`1.3`), the first field of the second file (`2.1`) and the 1st field of the first file (`1.1)`.

Alternatively, you could combine the entire thing in one gloriously complicated command:

```
$ join -o 1.1,2.2,2.3,2.1 -1 2 -2 1  --nocheck-order <(sort -k2 file3) \
      <(join -j2  --nocheck-order <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k2 file2)) 
9 10 3 Hac.2
23 1 33 Hhe.7
70 2 15 Hpyl.1
```

---

If you don't like arcane command line-fu, you can always use a little script:

```
$ awk '{a[$NF]=$1"\t"a[$NF];} END{for(i in a){print a[i],i}}' file{1,2,3} 
23  33  1    Hhe.7
9   3   10   Hac.2
70  15  2    Hpyl.1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for `join`, which can join on common fields of two files:

```
$ join -11 -22 -o1.2,1.3,2.1,0 <(join -j2 <(sort -k2,2 f1.txt) <(sort -k2,2 f2.txt)) <(sort -k2,2 f3.txt)
10 3 9 Hac.2
1 33 23 Hhe.7
2 15 70 Hpyl.1
```

As `join` takes only two input files at a time, we have used process substitution (`<()`) to pass the output of `join`-ing first two files with the third.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '!(a[$2]){a[$2]=$1;next}
{a[$2]=a[$2]"\t"$1} 
END{
for ( i in a) {
    print a[i],i
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from:

- [shell script - Merge some tab-delimited files - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177099/merge-some-tab-delimited-files/177136#177136)

> The following script ought to do an outer join on column (field) 1 of
>   all the tab-delimited files passed as arguments. It uses the
>   [join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html)
>   command, which does an outer join on sorted files, 2 files at a time.
>
> It will join every line in the files, including the header lines. If
>   you want the headers to be excluded, change the two `sort` commands to
>   something that produces a sorted file that omits them.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> if test $# -lt 2
> then
>     echo usage: gjoin file1 file2 ...
>     exit 1
> fi
> sort -t $'\t' -k 1 "$1" > result
> shift
> for f in "$@"
> do
>     sort -t $'\t' -k 1 "$f" > temp
>     join -1 1 -2 1 -t $'\t' result temp > newresult
>     mv newresult result
> done
> cat result
> rm result temp
> ```
>
> If you have an older shell, `$'\t'` will not be replaced by a tab, so
>   you'll need to use  <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>, where you
>   put a literal tab between the quotes.
>
> Optimizations are possible if, instead of `/bin/sh`, you can use a
>   modern shell such as bash or ksh; for instance, the lines
>
> ```
> sort -t $'\t' -k 1 "$f" > temp
> join -1 1 -2 1 -t $'\t' result temp > newresult
> ```
>
> can be replaced by
>
> ```
> join -1 1 -2 1 -t $'\t' result <(sort -t $'\t' -k 1 "$f") > newresult
> ```